# Railroad Track plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a plugin that would allow me to display divergent options on a horizontal track (a la branching and merging in Git). I really don't know the proper term for this so searching is quite difficult.

something like this:

```
 o----o-----o----o
      |
      ------o----o
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be a kick star for you [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

In this there are two plugins are mentioned

1. [Graph.js](http://gitgraphjs.com/)
2. [Gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/)
3. [Gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/)

I will prefer 1.

Comment: thanks, though i'm not going to use it for git specifically though. I just want something to create a similar UI with additional labels at each point. I also want to change the color of each edge and point as well

Comment: Then may be i misunderstood your point. http://gitgraphjs.com/ didn't work for you with some modification according to your use ?